# how to get response back from mule server to my own application

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I've gone through [AnyPoint Connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Connector+Tutorial) tutorial of mulesoft. Here Following this tutorial I was able to get response in logger in mule studio console. Then I thought to to one step further, to create a web application and get response back to my application html file. In this way I am getting response as a file which is of type Application/octate-stream But I want a json response.

I have no idea to do this. Please tell me the way. I am very new to mule and web services stuff. In fact I started my study on mule two days back only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "Object to JSON" from Mule toolbar "Transformers" list, and add that as the last component inside the flow.